# Detecting errors during PHP's parsing of multidimensional POST data

Tags: php, post

When PHP is parsing multidimensional data into $_POST, and it hits part of a name that it doesn't understand, it just uses what it has got so far.

For example:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form action=# method=post>
<input type=text value='hello' name='a[b]c]'>  <!-- note missing [ before c -->
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Results in:

```
array (size=1)
   'a' => 
      array (size=1)
         'b' => string 'hello' (length=5)
```

What's the best way to detect cases such as this one, where the "c]" is being discarded from the name?

I'm using the multidimensional $_POST feature to avoid having to implement one myself, so ideally I'm after a solution that captures warnings from the PHP implementation.

Comment: I believe that is an HTML mistake that results in `$_POST` not being populated how you would like. Don't think there is much you can do about bad HTML other than correct the HTML before the form is submitted

Comment: Yeah PHP isn't the cause of this issue, the browser creates the `POST` data from the form and sends it through the request.

Comment: The only way to detect this would be to write your own `x-www-form-urlencoded` parser that checks for it, and have it read `php://stdin`.

Comment: not true, i've encountered the problem before, there is a solution, its just very complex and involves regex and getting the raw request parameters.

Comment: @asimes, @sjagr: The browser seems to be generating the encoded version correctly.  This can be verified by adding: `$raw_post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($raw_post_data);` to my example.

Comment: @Barmar: I was afraid of that.  I'm using the [] mechanism specifically to avoid implementing one myself.

Comment: HTML knows nothing about arrays. That PHP treats the CGI parameter x[y] as the yth elemnt of an array x is purely a PHP thing. As to whether PHP should be reporting an error when it tries to parse the name is a more complex question. After all it should be the developers problem to make sure that his code works - errors and warnings are only a clue.

Comment: (BTW PHP knows nothing about multi-dimensional arrays - only nested arrays)

Comment: @symcbean: It's the developer's job.  And the easier the language makes that job, the better the language.  I think the ability to enable warnings would make the job easier.

Comment: @symcbean: Good point about the nested arrays.  It looks like "multidimensional array via POST" is the more popular term for the feature though, otherwise I'd edit the title.

Answer (score 1):

This regex is very basic, you might try expanding it(or editing my post)

```
function get_raw_post(){
    $raw = file_get_contents("php://input");
    return ( strpos('&',$raw) !== false ) ? post_get_associative( explode( '&',$raw ) ) || array();
}

function post_get_associative($post){
    $new = array();
    foreach($post as $key => $val) {
        if (preg_match("/(.\S+\[+.+\]+)/", $key,$match)) {
            $new[$match[1]] = $val;
        }else{
            $new = $val;
        }
    }
    return $new;
}
```

use like so

`$post = get_raw_post();`

Comment: Certainly a possible solution.  I've added a note to the question that I'm trying to avoid writing (or more importantly, maintaining) a parser myself.

Comment: @TimSmith i understand. Originally i wrote this for an app i built using the symfony http library, which for some reason was not working with associative-ish key names like `foo[5]` or `foo[bar]`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like PHP can't generate warnings there, so it's impossible without recompiling PHP.[1]

I ended up using something like this to check manually:

```
#print out a list of POST variables from the raw input.  
#Variables where part of the name is discarded by the parser are tagged "BAD".
function abz_post_check() {
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    echo "<pre>testing post vars";
    foreach (explode("&", $raw_post_data) as $var) {
        abz_post_var_check($var);
    }
    echo "</pre>";
    var_dump($raw_post_data);
}
function abz_post_var_check($var) {
    if (empty($var)) {
        return;
    }
    if (false !== strpos($var, '=')) {
      list($key, $value) = explode("=", $var);
    } else {
      $key = $var;
      $value = '';
    }
    $key = urldecode($key)

    #pattern matches only
    #  'string-without-['  followed by any number of 'string-in-[]'
    #note that 'string-without-[' is not a precise description of
    #what PHP matches, but it's good enough for my purposes.
    if (!preg_match('/^[^[]+(\[[^[\]]*\])*$/', $key)) {
        echo "<span style='color: red'> BAD: $key</span>\n";
    } else {
    echo "GOOD: $key\n";
    }
}
abz_post_check();
```

[1] I think the relevant code in the PHP source is in `php_register_variable_ex()` and the only warning it can display is "Input variable nesting level exceeded".   https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4b943c9c0dd4114adc78416c5241f11ad5c98a80/main/php_variables.c

Comment: @symcbean: It seems to work and the other possibilities seemed like they'd take longer.  I would welcome a better solution.

Comment: Longer to implement, that is.